# Firefox causes vertically adjacent images to bump to side

Tags: html, css

I can't for the life of me figure this out.

I've got two DIVs stacked on top of each other, each with an image that also stacks on top of each other to create a sort of two-part logo. It works fine on Chrome and Safari, but for some reason, the bottom image is bumped to the right.

Almost like a text wrap, but I can't figure out why that would be because there's no reason Firefox should think these images are overlapping.

[Chrome Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdL7J.png)

[Firefox Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6oL2.png)

I've been working on this all afternoon and can't find a solution, so thanks in advance for any help.

Relevant HTML:

```
<div id="top_blue">
   <div class="imgholder1"><img src="./img/top_half_white.png"></div>
</div>

<div id="top_green">
    <div class="imgholder2"><img src="./img/bottom_half.png"></div>
</div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
    #top_blue {
       background: rgb(34,59,141);
       width: 100%;
       height: 80px;
   }

   #top_green {
       background: rgb(10,128,55);
       width: 100%;
       height: 47px;
   }

   #top_blue img, #top_green img {
       width: 258px;
   }

   .imgholder1, .imgholder2 {
       margin-left: 20%;
       float: left;
       overflow: hidden;
   }
```

Comment: Forgot link. Ugh. http://www.sandrakurt.com/testing

Comment: Links go bad and then the question has no value for future readers.  Paste the code into your question.

Comment: as Jim said, post the code in the question, and perhaps a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) _in addition to_ the posted code, and I would will upvote because its an interesting question.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, @JimGarrison and thedarklord47. Pasted code into question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the following to the css for `.imageholder1, .imageholder2`

```
clear: left;
```

nice looking star by the way!

Comment: Such a simple solution. Works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the height to 81px on `#top_blue` fixed the problem in Firefox for me.

Answer (score 0):

add this:

```
#top_green {clear:both;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need:

1. a container;
2. clearfix;
3. proper use of floats and margins;
4. complete logo and not divided (give me the complete image and i will give you the css)

HTML:

```
<header class='block'>

  <top class='block'>
    <div class='container clearfix'>
      <div id='logo'>&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </top>

  <nav class='block'>
    <div class='container'>
      <ul class='clearfix'>
        <li><a href=''>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href=''>About</a></li>
        <li><a href=''>Endorsements</a></li>
        <li><a href=''>Contribute</a></li>
        <li><a href=''>Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

</header>

<main>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='red'>some text here</div>
  </div>
</main>
```

CSS:

```
*
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

li
{
  list-style: none;
}

.red
{
  background: red;
}

.container
{
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
}

.block
{
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.clearfix
{
  display: block;
}

.clearfix::before, 
.clearfix::after
{
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
}

top
{
  background: blue;
}

top #logo
{
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  float: left;
}


nav
{
  background: green;
}

nav ul {
  float: right;
}
nav ul li{
  float: left;
}

nav ul li a
{
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

FOR THE LOGO:

if the logo's height is 200px and the nav's height is 50px, than the top's height must be 150px (fixed and declared height in the .css). In this way the logo will be on the nav bar but inside the  tag.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/michmammo93/h8r27oq4/